# jQuery Equivalent of Prototype Function bind()

Tags: jquery, prototype, bind

How to write the following code with jQuery:

```
td.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this, "abc");
```

Sorry, i forget the other thing. the td element is been created, as:

```
td = document.createElement("td");
td.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this, "abc");
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Can i use $(td).click($.proxy(this.onclick, this)) before appendChild the element.

And which is important, how about the parameter "abc".

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
td.onclick = $.proxy(this.onclick, this);
```

But in jQuery it should be

```
$(td).click($.proxy(this.onclick, this))
```

Comment: sorry, i forget the other thing. the td element is been created, as

Answer (score 0):

There is bind function in JavaScript, you can find what browsers support it [here](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$("td").on("click",function(){
   alert("clicked cell");
});
```

//or if you wanna call another event control, you could try this:

```
$("span").on("click",function(){
   alert("clicked span");
});

$("td").on("click",function(){
   $("span").click();

   //OR,
   $("span").trigger("click");
});
```

i hope it helps.